# React Typescript passing interface props to component, results in error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am currently learning React js and typescript. I have a demo app that can be used to enter users I.e. a name and an age. The App includes an ErrorModal that should show up on the screen if the user tries to submit incorrect data I.e. the username or age fields are blank or age is not between certain values.

Below I have only included code I thought was relevant but let me know if I need to include other parts or the whole code.

I have used a Typescript interface to define an error as having a title and message ..

```
export interface IError { 
    errorTitle: string; 
    errorMessage: string; 
    onConfirmError?(): void; 

}
```

I am using the useState method to set the error state if invalid data is entered.

e.g.

```
const [error, setError] = useState<IError | null | undefined>(); 

const addUserHandler = (event: any) => { 
    event.preventDefault();     
    if(enteredUsername.trim().length === 0 ){ 
        setError({ 
            errorTitle: 'Invalid Username',  
            errorMessage: 'Username must be more than 4 characters', 
}) 
return;
```

....

In the AddUser component I display the error modal within the component return statement if there is an error with ..

```
... 

{error && <ErrorModal error={error} onConfirmError={errorHandler}/>} 
...
```

But this gives me the error ..

Type '{ error: IError; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IError'.
Property 'error' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IError'.

I can get around this by having individual props for the title and message and the onConfirmError method and passing those as props with ..

```
{error && <ErrorModal  
    errorTitle={error.errorTitle}  
    errorMessage={error.errorMessage}  
    onConfirmError={errorHandler}/>
```

But I thought if I am defining an error as an instance of an interface that it is more proper to pass that as props. So my question is there an easy fix for this issue or am I going about this the wrong way?

This is the code for my ErrorModal ..

```
type Props = IError; 

const ErrorModal: React.FC<Props> = (props) => { 
return ( 
<div> 
    <div className={styles.backdrop} onClick={props.onConfirmError}/> 
        <Card className={styles.modal}> 
            <header className={styles.header}> 
                <h2>{props.errorTitle}</h2> 
            </header> 
            <div className={styles.content}> 
                <p>{props.errorMessage}</p> 
            </div> 
            <footer className={styles.actions}> 
                <Button onClick={props.onConfirmError}>OK</Button> 
            </footer> 
        </Card> 
    </div> 
) 
} 

export default ErrorModal;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-danilo-7yz878?file=/src/ErrorModal.tsx Can you have a look at this?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
interface IError { 
    errorTitle: string; 
    errorMessage: string; 
    onConfirmError?(): void; 
}

type Props = IError; 

const ErrorModal: React.FC<Props>(props) => //...
```

expects the component to have the props `errorTitle`, `errorMessage` and `onConfirmError`.

Like this:

```
<ErrorModal
  errorTitle="Oh no!"
  errorMessage="Bad stuff happened"
  onConfirmError={() => console.log('confirmed')}
/>
```

But you passed it:

```
<ErrorModal
  error={error}
  onConfirmError={errorHandler}
/>
```

You never defined a prop named `error` so you get this type error message:

> Type '{ error: IError; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IError'.
>
> **Property 'error' does not exist on type** 'IntrinsicAttributes & IError'.

---

To fix it, either pass in each error prop individially:

```
error && <ErrorModal
  errorTitle={error.errorTitle}
  errorMessage={error.errorMessage}
  onConfirmError={errorHandler}
/>
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsBQXwAdpSh10VAJIBRKIyi44XOArhIp0ACrAYAGyQAuOIRhR+AcwDccxUpVQAskkKEUx3fsMnz8xRD4Bhb3WAoEElpAH4ACgBKPQA3CGAAEw9qHhgATzAqAAVGMEI4AF44CWsPLjRvAzgQ6BsIBJRNPWR0GAA6ADEfAB4ciDyAPkK4cLBcwkjCobxPBXYYfCg+OG6B7oB6Ia5aHjp8PgxgbzgbNL9wbyQBKNxZuAq+KoBtZWlsYhgaqABdYaJSciUbolaRwAA+cD4+E0mnBBD4CSQAT4SASAyiZUs80Wy1WOFe0DgADIiSsvnUGrCCVB1FokAV8dY2tTadpaNS7A4nPTGdJmdZOY5nLRNtQNgNtkA)

Or change your props to accept an `error` prop:

```
interface IError { 
    errorTitle: string; 
    errorMessage: string; 
    onConfirmError?(): void; 
}

type Props = { error: IError }; // now has an `error` property

const ErrorModal: React.FC<Props>(props) => //...
```

Which you would call by passing your error object to like this:

```
error && <ErrorModal error={error} />
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsBQXwAdpSh10VAJIBRKIyi44XOArhIp0ACrAYAGyQAuOIRhR+AcwDccxUpVQAskkKEUx3fsMnz8xRD4Bhb3WAoEElpAH4ACgBKPQA3CGAAEw9qHhgATzAqAAVGMEI4AF5ZZWk9CWsaDy40bwM4EOgbCASUTT1kdBgAOgAxHwAeHIg8gD5CuHCwXMJIwrG8TwV2GHwoPjh+kf6AejGuWh46fD4MYG84GzS-cG8kASjcRbgavjqAbRLobGIYBqgAXXGRFI5Eo-XK0jgAB84Hx8JpNNCCHwEkgAnwkAkRlEPJZlqt1pscJ8ZAAyUkbP5NFqIkkFYnWWi7ag7Eb7IA)

Comment: Thanks Alex. That kind've works although now clicking on the ErrorModal ok button does not close the modal i.e. the method to set the error back to null doesn't run..  i.e. the errorHandler method within AddUser that is pointed to by onConfirmError prop. I will look into this.